# Reactive Validation Angular 5: Writing Custom validator for comparing two controls

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want my save button to be disabled only when my validation fails...
Validation1 : startTime < endTime
Validation2 : Either both are null OR both have data(already in 24hr-hh:mm).
My IMPLEMENTATION-
1. .ts file:

```
private createForm() {
    this.commentForm = new FormGroup({
     'startTime': new 
      FormControl(this.startTime, 
      [
       this.openCloseTimeValidator
      ]),
     'endTime': new 
      FormControl(this.endTime, [
      this.openCloseTimeValidator
    ]),});
  }

openCloseTimeValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const commentFormGroup = control.root;
    const startTime = ((commentFormGroup.get('startTime')) ? 
    commentFormGroup.get('startTime').value : null);
    const endTime = ((commentFormGroup.get('endTime')) ? 
    commentFormGroup.get('endTime').value : null);
    return startTime && endTime && (startTime >= endTime) ?
               { 'openCloseTimeValidator' : true } : null;
 }
```

2. .html file

```html
<form  [formGroup]="commentForm">
  <div formGroupName="noiseOrdinance">
  <div fxFlex class= "time-picker">
    <time-picker  placeholder="Start Time"
      formControlName="startTime"  type="text"></time-picker>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex class= "time-picker">
  <time-picker  placeholder="End Time" formControlName="endTime" 
    type="text"></time-picker>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button mat-button [disabled]="!commentForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

This validation is not working properly, consider a case when initially startTime< endTime, now decrease endTime to be smaller to startTime , then again make startTime to be less than EndTime.---> Save would be disabled but its wrong it should be in abled state.

The validation values gets updated if a check and uncheck html-snippet enclosed in a checkbox. But
On Console Log: I get **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError**

Comment: can you create plunker/stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your description you mention that the validation should be `startTime < endTime`, but in the validator you typed `startTime && endTime && (startTime >= endTime)`.

In any way, your validator could look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ValidatorFn, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

const timeValidator: ValidatorFn = (ctrl: FormGroup) => {
  const start = ctrl.get('startTime').value;
  const end = ctrl.get('endTime').value;

  return start && end && start < end ? null : { 'timeError': true };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="number" formControlName="startTime" />
    <input type="number" formControlName="endTime" />
  </form>

  Valid: {{ form.valid }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  // pretend it's epoch time
  startTime = 1000;
  endTime = 2000;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      startTime: [this.startTime],
      endTime: [this.endTime],
    }, { validator: timeValidator })
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7zxsm)

Comment: Thnx man I was missing how to bind two fields with...
Below form with your validator works like a charm.

'

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you upvote and accept my answer? :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the same in an alternate way i.e. using ngmodel and ngModelChange:

For an example:

In your HTML,

add these two consecutively in the two `<time-picker>` tag

```
[(ngModel)]="searchTimeIni" (ngModelChange)=checkValid() 
[(ngModel)]="searchTimeFin" (ngModelChange)=checkValid()
```

And button tag as

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="!valid">Save</button>
```

In TS file

```
valid: boolean = false;



checkValid() {


    if (this.searchTimeIni=== undefined && this.searchTimeFin=== undefined) {
      this.valid = false;

    }
    else if (this.searchTimeIni< this.searchTimeFin) { 


      this.valid = true;
    }
    else if (this.searchTimeIni> this.searchTimeFin) { 


      this.valid = false;
    }


  }
```